# Where can I find the function called by onclick using Inspect Element of Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I found in my university website there is a button to add course. Where can I find the function `addNewCourseToStudent()`details using inspect element of the google chrome.

`<button onclick="addNewCourseToStudent()">Add</button>`

Comment: look on script tags in the html / php file from that button or in js files included in that file..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inline handler will almost certainly be referencing a global variable, so you can open the console and log the variable, which will give you the function location and its code:

```js
const foo = 'some code';
function fn() {
  console.log('fn running');
}

// when you have the function name, console.dir it
// to find its location:
console.dir(fn);
// console.log it to find its code:
console.log(fn);
```

[image]

You can click on the link to the right of the `[[FunctionLocation]]` to get to the place in the Sources panel where the function is defined.

Comment: is there any chance to edit that code for the time being?

Comment: Yes, you can overwrite it, just assign to the window property. `window.fn = () => { }`

Answer (score 2):

Right click inspect the tag or button, 
Choose the Event Listeners Tab in the developer tools as shown below

[image: Ctrl Shift I]

Expand `click` it won't show as onclick it will show as `click`

[image]

Comment: then open source/browse in the developer tools, it will show all the codes